# How to find the full amount of calculated VAT amount

Tags: percentages

How to find the full amount of Calculated Vat value?

Here i have calculated VAT Amount from Full amount.

VAT Percentage 10%

Full Amount = 100

VAT Amount = ???

= (10/100)

= 0.1

= 0.1 * 100

= 10 (VAT)

= 100 - 10

= 90 (VAT Amount - After calculated VAT 10%)

---

Need the Full Amount??? (Only VAT 10% and already calculated VAT amount 90)

VAT Percentage 10%

Already Calculated VAT amount = 90

Full Amount = ???

Answer (score 1):

If the VAT is $10\%=0.10$, we multiply the pre-tax price by $1.10$ to get the final price.  So if the final price is $100$, the pre-tax price is $\frac {100}{1.1}\approx 90.91$ and $90.91 \cdot 1.1 \approx 100$

Comment: What is pre-tax price by 1.10, I want to get final price of Vat Percentage and already calculated vat amount (need actual price of calculated vat amount)

Comment: Please answer with example.. thank you

Comment: I gave an example, using your value for the final price of $100$.  The VAT amount is the difference between $100$ and the pre-tax price.  Can you subtract?

Comment: Thank for the answer, but i couldn't understand 1.10 and what is value of 90.91.11 please explain me...

Comment: VAT is 11%, After calculated VAT 11% of x value VAT amount is 111.25. What is the X value

Comment: Your example was VAT of $10\%$, so I multiplied by $1+0.10=1.1$.  For VAT of $11\%=0.11$, you multiply by $1.11$  I showed how I got $90.91,$ I divided $100$ by $1.1$  When you increase something by $x\%$, that is $x/100$, so the price becomes $1+(x/100)$ times the previous price.

Comment: i understood but answer is not coming. Can you do it and show what is the original price of VAT 11% deducted price 111.25

Comment: @user1663855  If the price is $111.25$ after a VAT of $11\%$ is added, then the original price was $\frac{111.25}{1.11}$.

Comment: The Original price is wrong i divided 111.25 by 1.11 answer coming 100.2252252252252 something like this...

Comment: Why do you say that original price is not correct?  If the original price were $100$, the price with tax would be $111$.  This with tax price is just a little higher.  Prices are often rounded off, so you can't count on division coming out evenly.